# THREE.PointsMaterial Size

Tags: three.js

I'm using a THREE.Points mesh to display images.  The points of the image interact and can fly around the scene.  But I'm having issues with THREE.PointsMaterial Size property.

Using a Size of 1, I expected two points next to each other to aligned and touching without a gap.  However, my experience is that there is a significant gap between pixels.  For example, vertex x:10,y:10 and x:11,y:10 are not touching and have a gap between them.

I have experimented with increasing the pixel size to remove the gap and found a size of 2.5 sort of works.

Why do I need to use a size of ~2.5 to get two points to align without a gap?
Can I adjust the mesh|scene|renderer units/ratio so that a size of 1 will align the pixels without a gap?

Here is a snippet of my code for creating the Points mesh:

`var g = new THREE.Geometry();
 for (i = 0; i < imgData.pixels.length; i++) {
   g.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(imgData.pixels[i].x - (imgData.width / 2), 0 - imgData.pixels[i].y + (imgData.height / 2), 0));
   g.colors.push(new THREE.Color(imgData.pixels[i].color));
 }
 var mat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ size:1, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
 points = new THREE.Points(g, mat);
 points.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
 world.scene.add(points);`

[Pixel Size 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLnNH.png)
[Pizel Size 2.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUhpI.png)

Comment: try sizeAttenuation: false in points material. I think it is caused by perspective. Or change a camera FOV, or change scale of scene. (precision is linear on difference between  camera far - camera near number) beware of high numbers, as a position 46446456465465.5454654 is visually the same like 46.4464564654655454654, but much more precise.

Comment: I have already tried experimenting with sizeAttenuation: false, however I found the results to be worse and less controllable as the points move.  I have also looking at the scene scale, but had little success.  I figured it would be related to the perspective and linked to the camera, but not sure I understand that all too well.  I'll try experimenting with the FOV.  Until then, a value of 2.5 gives me the results I'm looking for, I was just looking for understanding and was unsure if this was costing me any performence.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Also stuck with this. Any luck? Seems like directly changing the material.size does nothing.